# Include github project into wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, gchart

I would like to use the following php wrapper in my wordpress plugin.

[PHP Object wrapper for the Google Chart API](https://github.com/pacbard/gChartPhp)

However, the installation description says that composer has to be used, which I am not using for managing dependencies.(it`s a really small plugin)

I am trying to include it the following way:

```
include(WPPLUGIN_PATH. 'gcharts/ClassLoader.php');
```

However, this does not work. I guess I haven`t included the right php-class.

Any suggestions which php-file has to be included to make the example run?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `examples.php` file in repo you provided.

There's:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/gchart/gChartInit.php");
?>
```