# Loading github project into wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, github

I am trying to use the following github project in my wordpress plugin:

[PHP Object wrapper for the Google Chart API](https://github.com/pacbard/gChartPhp)

I tried the following:

```
 require_once(WPPLUGIN_PATH. "gchart/gChartInit.php");

 $piChart = new gPieChart(); // <---- here I get the error

 $piChart->addDataSet(array(112,315,66,40));
 $piChart->setLabels(array("first", "second", "third","fourth"));
 $piChart->setLegend(array("first", "second", "third","fourth"));
 $piChart->setColors(array("ff3344", "11ff11", "22aacc", "3333aa"));
 echo $piChart->getImgCode();
```

My problem seems to be that when I am using the above code, it jumps at line `$piChart = new gPieChart();` into another wordpress-plugins autoloader and does not load the `gPieChart.php` properly.

The error message is:

```
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'gPieChart' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/plugins/wp-analytics-mail/sendTestMail.php on line 267
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP   2. require() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:17
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-blog-header.php:19
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP   4. include() /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/template-loader.php:75
[26-Jul-2016 20:39:59 UTC] PHP   5. include() /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/page-analytics-analytics-mail.php:138
```

Any suggestions how to make the above code work?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598182/include-github-project-into-wordpress-plugin -- if you are not using composer you will need to build a autoloader yourself unless there is one there

Comment: @montrealist Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do.

1. Install Composer as per [the doc](https://github.com/pacbard/gChartPhp) or, if you're on Windows/Unix, figure out how to install [the thing](https://getcomposer.org/) in your environment.
2. Create new file called `composer.json` in the root folder of your plugin (in this case `wp-analytics-mail`)
3. Again, as per the doc, paste this into the `composer.json`

`{
         "require": {
              "gchartphp/gchartphp": "dev-master"
         }
    }`

4. In the command line, get to the plugin folder and run `composer update`
5. Put `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` somewhere close to the top of your main plugin file (`sendTestMail.php`)
6. Lower down in the same file, initialize and use the library:

`$piChart = new gchart\gPieChart();`